# Migrating from EC2 to Proxmox VM

Tags: amazon-ec2, virtual-machines, migration, dedicated-server, clone

So I am currently running 3 servers on EC2 with total of 3 cores. And 4 GB for the main server and 1 gb each for the dns servers. The bill doesn't make any sense to me paying 70 ish $ a month. I decided to move to dedicated server. I installed proxmox. The problem is i just can't find an easy way to image the EC2 which have centos 7 cloudlinux converted and cpanel on it. I just want to take that system iso boot it in proxmox and boom. Idk it might be too much to ask. I really need help. I need to image or clone the ec2 and boot it into my proxmox. The ec2 using EBS so I can use Amazon migrating tool. Any idea?

Answer (score 1):

[AWS VM export](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/vm-import/latest/userguide/vmexport.html) has several limitations.

Instead, create new instances on Proxmox, and do a restore of your data from backup.

When you only have EBS snapshots, [attach them to a temporary EC2 instance](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/compute/recovering-files-from-an-amazon-ebs-volume-backup/). Do a file based backup, your own scripts or third party data protection software.